# how to use GOOGLE Android Calendar API in 2021

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I try to create simple app which enables me to create event on google calendar. I try to use quick start and instructions from google guides but it doesn't work for me. I try this:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java

But their require from me to replace whole gradle build file by their code, when i do that, app doesn't want to compile, when i just add required libraries acctualy i have access to some classes but not all for example:

```
  View.header("Show Calendars");
    CalendarList feed = client.calendarList().list().execute();
    View.display(feed);
```

I have access to View but not to header and display methods. I have access to CalendarList but not for client and go on.

I tried another solution from this page: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java

Gradle compile but nothing is happend, i try later add some code from first solution but have same problem. Could someone give me simple snipped of code include dependencies and java/kotlin class please.

Comment: Hi ! If you follow the quickstart sample and run this line after ```CalendarList``` what do you get ```System.out.println(feed);```? Are you getting the list of calendars on the console?

Comment: I can't compile this code as I wrote, I don't have access to client.calendarList()....

Comment: What do you mean by ```I cant compile this code```? Are you getting any error messages and if so which ones? Also how come you cant print ```feed``` on the console?